# Access 2000 Report -- alternate row color

Tags: ms-access, vba

I inherited a MS Access database and at my new job.  I don't know much about Access and they asked if I could make every other line of a report a different color so it is easier to read.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do.  The easiest way I found to do this is to use the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ColorDetail As Boolean

Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
   If ColorDetail Then
      Detail.BackColor = 16777215
   Else
      Detail.BackColor = 13290186
   End If
   ColorDetail = Not (ColorDetail)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding.  A clear cut answer is what I was looking for.  It worked great and made the co-workers happy.

Comment: Your welcome, not all solutions have to be difficult, :).  Glad I could help

Comment: Ah that is a typo it should of been ColorDetail.  I have corrected the answer.